# Question about $C_f \approx \mathbb R P^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to understand why the mapping cone $C_f$ (where $f: S^1 \to S^1, \space e^{2\pi it} \mapsto e^{4 \pi i t}$) is homeomorphic to the real projective space $\mathbb R P^2$. If we use the definition where $\mathbb R P^2$ is identified with $B^2$ and the equivalence relation $x \sim -x$ on the boundary $\partial B^2=S^1$.

Define the following map:

$$F: S^1 \sqcup (S^1 \times I) \to \mathbb R P^2$$

by mapping $(e^{2 \pi i t},s) \mapsto [(1-s)e^{2\pi i t}]$ and $e^{2 \pi i t} \mapsto [e^{\pi i t}]$.

My question now is how one sees that such a map is actually continuous.

For $s \in (0,1]$ it's clear as the equivalence relation is trivial on the interior of $B^2$ but how does it work out on the boundary?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping cone of $f$ is the quotient of $S^1\times I\cup S^1$ by $(x,0)\simeq (x',0)$ and $(x,1)\simeq f(x)$. The quotient of $S^1\times I$ by $(x,0)\simeq (x',0)$ is $D^2$ and to obtain the mapping cone here, you make the quotient of $D^2$ by $e^{it}\rightarrow e^{2it}$. The fibres of this map are the antipodal points. So the resulting quotient is $RP^2$.

Comment: 'My question now is how one sees that such a map is actually continuous.' This is not what I'm looking for I'm afraid.

Comment: The map $D^2\rightarrow PR^2$ here is exactly the quotient of its boundary by $x\rightarrow -x$, to see this remark that the fiber of $e^{it}\rightarrow e^{2it}$ are antipodal points so this map is continuous.